# What's a time-dependent vector field?

Tags: vector-fields

Question might seem silly, but I can't put it together. Suppose we got a vector field $V: \textbf{x}\in U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ so for instance for 3 Dimensions any point $(x,y,z)$ is pointing to another point $V(\textbf{x}) = \left(\begin{array}{c} v_1(x,y,z) \\v_2(x,y,z) \\ v_3(x,y,z) \end{array}\right)$ forming a vector. Now a time-dependent vector field is defined as $(t,x) \to V_t(\textbf{x})$. How's it looking? $V_t(\textbf{x}) = \left(\begin{array}{c} v_1(x,y,z,t) \\v_2(x,y,z,t) \\ v_3(x,y,z,t) \end{array}\right)$ ? The point to that a point $(x,y,z)$ is pointing to is changing in time?

Comment: You have answered your question correctly.

Comment: An example is the wind velocity (i.e. speed and direction). It varies over both space and time.

Comment: You can find other examples in physics, the electric field $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},t)$ and magnetic field $\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r},t)$